# Query Execution Plan Analysis

Tags: sql-server, database-design, execution-plan

I've recently started my journey as a dba and I found those interesting scripts by Brent Ozar to check the health of my database. I run some of the scripts and I figure out that there are some huge problems going on. Result of the sp_BlitzCache:[image: Problematic Queries]

The Plan Warnings got my attention so I decided to analyze the execution plan of the selected query.

[Estimated Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryPJM67xo)

[Actual Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyQLgwNei)

As I am a beginner I'm not being able to completely understand what's happening with that query. Can you guys gimme some insights?

Comment: Can you run this query and provide the **actual** execution plan instead?

Comment: @J.D. I don't see the difference, the link is the actual execution plan formatted via XML... I'm gonna provide it anyways.

Comment: The link you've provided so far is an estimated iteration of the plan. The only way to get the actual plan is to run the query with actual plans enabled. It contains runtime information not available in the estimated plan, such as `Actual Number of Rows` for each operator.

Comment: @J.D. ooh, I see! Thanks for explaining. The query is actually a stored procedure called by a vb.net program. Should I run it passing specific values and post here the actual execution plan?

Comment: Np. This is probably going to be a little tougher to unpack as parameterized stored procedures have a few complexities (e.g. parameter sniffing) to account for, and little differences like running the code directly vs running it from the app can *sometimes* influence the execution plan (based on connection parameters). All that aside, yes, if you're able to run the procedure, and ideally with the same parameters as what's normally used, to get the actual plan, that would be helpful. There's probably some advisement that can be done looking at the query, but the actual plan is very helpful too.

Comment: BTW the tools from Brent Ozar are excellent and provide a plethora of information, but don't feel overwhelmed or like your database is on fire just because it points out a lot of things. The tools will alert you to even low priority / minor issue action items.

Comment: @J.D. I'm figuring out how to simulate with common parameters. Actually, this query is also showing huge problems in CloudWatch (mainly CPU) since my database is an amazon's rds.

Comment: @J.D. here you go... https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyQLgwNei

Comment: Did you mean that I should share the Actual Execution Plan analysis? @J.D.

Comment: That seems good enough. I added it to your post's body so others can see it too. I'm definitely seeing a few cardinality estimate issues - where the `Actual Number of Rows` is off by 10x or more from the `Estimated Number of Rows` (in either direction). That would probably be a good place to start. You can see that by starting all the way in the top right and hovering your mouse over each index operation, working downwards, and comparing those 2 properties. Using other information from the index operation should clue you in where the issue is in the query. If I get more time I'll look closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the warnings about the plan

```
   <Warnings>
      <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT(varchar(30),[MW].[hora_leit],23)" />
      <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT(varchar(30),[MW].[hora_leit],23)" />
      <MemoryGrantWarning GrantWarningKind="Excessive Grant" RequestedMemory="32496" GrantedMemory="32496" MaxUsedMemory="696" />
    </Warnings>
```

It's got many the nonSARGable predicates

```
DATEPART ( MINUTE , MX . HORA_LEIT ) = DATEPART ( MINUTE , D0 . HORA_LEIT )
```

Which among other things throw off the cardinality estimates, leading to the excessive memory grants.

Basically the issues with this query cause the estimated cost to be about 100x greater than the actual cost.  At the end of the day, the query runs pretty quickly:

```
<WaitStats>
  <Wait WaitType="LATCH_EX" WaitTimeMs="1" WaitCount="3" />
  <Wait WaitType="PAGEIOLATCH_SH" WaitTimeMs="1" WaitCount="2" />
  <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="2" WaitCount="75" />
  <Wait WaitType="SESSION_WAIT_STATS_CHILDREN" WaitTimeMs="8" WaitCount="5" />
  <Wait WaitType="CXPACKET" WaitTimeMs="403" WaitCount="20" />
</WaitStats>
<QueryTimeStats CpuTime="312" ElapsedTime="239" />
```

So this query probably should be improved to remove these issues, you shouldn't expect the fixes to have a huge benefit.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. By that I think you are telling me that I should find a way to remove those nonSARGables predicates (DATEPART... ) and modify this (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,MW.HORA_LEIT,23)), am I right?

Comment: Normally a DBA wouldn't be directly responsible for the queries.

Comment: I am actually the only employee rsrs. Could you tell me why the convert(varchar...23) part has this cardinality estimate issue?